# Amazon Cognito Registration Confirmation

Tags: javascript, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, serverless, serverless-architecture

So, I am using (or at least trying to) Amazon Cognito with Lambda functions for auth.
Here's the flow: I send request, it goes to API Gateway, which directs it to a specific Lambda function.
I am using Node JS with amazon-cognito-identity-js library.
I am able to register user.
The thing is that, Cognito sends email with the confirmation code after the registration. I am unable to create another Lambda (API endpoint) function for confirmation, since it requires CognitoUser object (which you receive after registering or login). Here is the code from AWS documentation:

```
cognitoUser.changePassword('oldPassword', 'newPassword', function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
            alert(err);
            return;
        }
        console.log('call result: ' + result);
    });
```

So basically, it's not designed for Lambda functions, since it requires to save the state - the user after the registration. 
Am I getting it wrong? Is there a way?

Answer (score 3):

Oh, ok, my bad. 
Apparently you can create a CognitoUser object using only username and user pool:

```
const poolData = {    
    UserPoolId : process.env.COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID,
    ClientId : process.env.COGNITO_CLIENT_ID
};
const userPool = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserPool(poolData);
...
const userData = { 
        Username : email,
        Pool : userPool
};
```

and then you can call

```
cognitoUser.confirmRegistration(confirmationCode, true, function(err, result) {
            if (err) {
                alert(err);
                return;
            }
            alert(result);
        });
```

Comment: how do you know the email of the user? the login happens all at a cognito login page and you just receive a code!? in theory I must validate the code againts the Cognito API and get a token WITH the user data (including the email address)